# Connecting similar lines from two files

Tags: python

I have two files, both are very big. The files have mixed up information between themselves and I need to compare two files and connect the lines that intersect.

An example would be:

1st file has

```
var1:var2:var3
```

2nd would have

```
var2:var3:var4
```

I need to connect these in a third file with output: `var1:var2:var3:var4`.
Please note that the lines do not match, var4 which should go with var1 (since they have `var2` and `var3` together). Var2 and Var3 are common for Var1 and Var4. could be far away in these huge files.
I need to find a way to compare each line and connect it to the one in the 2nd file. I can't seem to think of anything of an adequate loop. Any ideas?

Comment: How do you discern when two lines "intersect?" Having two or more records ( "var _<n>_" in your example) in common? At least one in common?

Comment: The third file that is created must be in this format: var1:var2:var3:var4. Var2 and var3 are common for var1 and var3. Var2 and Var3 always go together in pairs, so if one is common so is the other.

Comment: Are you guaranteed that `var2` only occurs once in each file? Is the "intersection" guaranteed to exist only once between two files? I.e., given a line from file1, are there ever going to be more than one line that contain the records (e.g. `var2` or `var4`) it contains?

Comment: Absolutely. Var2 and Var3 are unique. Var4 is not.

Comment: Is memory (RAM) a constraint for the files in question? Do you want to avoid loading the entire file into memory?

Comment: What I mean is, are there multiple lines in file2 that could contain `var2` or `var4`?

Comment: I'm parsing a database. var1 is username, var2 is hash, var3 is salt & var4 is password. File1 contains username, hash and salt while file2 contains hash pass and salt. Passwords are in plain text. That should explain everything.

Comment: @user3184354, Build a dictionary that map (hash, salt) to password.

Comment: You should never store the plain text password of other users. This is a major security problem. Instead, save hashed password, the salt, and the one-way hashing algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the specific fields you said that you want to match (2 & 3 from file 1, 1 & 2 from file 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

# Iterate over every line in file1.
#   Iterate over every line in file2.
#     If lines intersect, print combined line.

with open('file1') as file1:
    for line1 in file1:
        u1,h1,s1 = line1.rstrip().split(':')

        with open('file2') as file2:
            for line2 in file2:
                h2,s2,p2 = line2.rstrip().split(':')

                if h1 == h2 and s1 == s2:
                    print(':'.join((u1,h1,s2,p2)))
```

This is *horrendously* slow (in theory), but uses a minimum of RAM. If the files aren't absolutely huge, it might not perform too badly.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following (assuming `var2:var3` is always a unique key in both files):

1. Iterate over all lines in the first file

   - Add all entries into a [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) with the value `var2:var3` as key (and `var1` as value)
2. Iterate over all entries in the second file

   - look up if the dictionary from part 1 contains an entry for the key `var2:var3` and if it does output `var1:var2:var3:var4` into the output file and delete the entry from the dictionary.

This approach can use very big amounts of memory and therefore should probably not be used for very large files.

Answer (score 0):

If memory isn't problem, use dictionary where the key is the same as the value:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

out_dict = {}

with open ('file1','r') as file_in:
    lines = file_in.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        out_dict[line] = line

with open ('file2','r') as file_in:
    lines = file_in.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        out_dict[line] = line

with open ('output_file','w') as file_out:
    for key in out_dict:
        file_out.write (key)
```

Comment: This one writes both lines that intersect and ones that don't.

Comment: Had i misunderstood you?  Any line will be shown only once:  If file1 is var1 <lf> var2 <lf> var3 <lf>, and file2 is var2 <lf> var3 <lf> var4 <lf> the output file will be var1 <lf> var2 <lf> var3 <lf> var4.  Wasn't this what you had asked for?